# What was the purpose of animating some of the dragons in the Dragon Manual?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

When Hiccup is reading about the dragon types from the manual at some point some of the dragons on the pages are shown as animated (very little general body movements on the manual pages) after he startles by the lightning. It looks like his imagination and fear gets to him. But why did they show those animated dragons just for a brief duration and then finished doing it? Was it referencing some older dragon related animation movie or was it just a little gimmick to make the younger viewers get into the mood?

Answer (score 3):

Basically the purpose of that was to gimmick to gain viewer's attention. Just to show what those dragons can do.

If you can check it out most of the dragons in the book were not shown in the movie.

Like below are two examples from the dragon book.

[image: Whispering Death]

[image: Second dragon]

These were not in the movie, so they animated them to show the details about what the past dragons were.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Interesting fact that the 3 animated ones with their names being mentioned weren't in the movie. But the one in your second screenshot isn't animated whereas we see a fourth animated one which isn't a dragon page but a caricatured fight scene. I'll wait a little longer before accepting your answer for possible alternate explanations. Thanks.

Comment: Sure Mate, Definitely the scenes are made like that to show some animations and attract the viewer. Animating whole of the dragon book scene may look like a sci-fi rather than a viking movie.

Comment: Hey Montag, i think 7 days are enough for searching. You can accept and close the question.